# Another LU decomposition?

Tags: matrices, permutations, matlab, lu-decomposition

I was asked to find **LU decomposition** of the following matrix without using a permutation:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

I found one of them but what is the second, any help?

$$L=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, U=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Moo But why? at class we learnt that we start with a1,1 and with the help of him we make the first line zeros then we go to a2,2 and using him we make the second line under him zeros too. at which point I had two choices?

Answer (score 1):

You have found that:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}=LU$$

Let $E$ corresponds to the elementary matrix of adding the third column to the second column.

Then we have $A=(LE)(E^{-1}U)$.

Notice that $E^{-1}U$ is still upper triangular, and $LE$ is still lower triangular. Furthermore, the diagonal of $LE$ consists of $1$ (if you impose such constraint). If you do not impose such constraint, consider $LU=(kL)(\frac1kU), k \ne 0$.

Alternatively,

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & x & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & y \end{bmatrix}$$

solve for $x$ and $y$.