# proving that lu decomposition is not unique on singular matrix.

Tags: matrices, matlab, positive-definite, singularity, lu-decomposition

How to prove that the following **isn't** true (using 3 by 3 matrix):

**Given A is a square and a singular matrix (which means non invertible), if LU decomposition is possible without the use of permutation, then the LU decomposition is not unique.**

**Any help?**

Comment: I thought I have answered your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3621865/306553) earlier.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Please note: I have updated the quote. I proved that it's actually true by finding A= [1,1,2;2,2,4;2,2,1] with 2 possible lu decompositions!

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh in that questions A is not singular here it should be

Comment: @Moo that book doesn't answer my question at all

Comment: the quote is wrong and I need an example for that!

Comment: @Moo reported you

Comment: @Moo you aren't trying to help at all! you gave me a book and I asked for an example or a method

Comment: the example in your previous quesiton is singular.

Comment: but that example doesn't work, read my question again @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: True, now that the question is changed. Also, you might want to state your convention of LU decomposition if any.

Comment: I didn't change the question here

Comment: the title and your question doesn't match btw.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Suppose you adopt the convention that $L$ is unit lower triangular.

$$L=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ l_{21} & 1 & 0 \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ and

$$U=\begin{bmatrix} u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} \\ 0 & u_{22}& u_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & u_{33}\end{bmatrix}$$

Direct computation show that it it unique.

From the first row of $A$, We can deduce that $u_{11}=1, u_{12}=0=u_{13}$.

From the second row of $A$, we can deduce that  $l_{21}=0$, and hence $u_{22}=1$, $u_{23}=0$.

From the third row, $l_{31}=0, l_{32}=0, u_{33}=0$.